# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter, this is my first model-controller connection,so anything you suggest is helpful for me and point will be considered for my future understanding,Kindly help to resolve here

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ci\CI_test\application\models\testquery.php on line 7
```

My Controller:

```
class Testdb extends CI_Controller
   {
    public function Index()
    {
        $this->load->model("testquery");
        $data['results'] = $this->testquery->query1();

        $this->load->view("view_db");
    }
   }
```

My Model is:

```
class Testquery extends CI_Model
{
    public function query1()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from color"); //this is line 7 error

        /**
        $sql = "SELECT * from color";       
        $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
           echo $row->color_id;
           echo $row->color_name;
           echo $row->color_desc;
        }
         */
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

My view is:

```
<<!DOCTYPE unspecified PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome db</h1>
<?php 
print_r($results);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**My connection details:**

config/database.php has-

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'varundb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

My config/autoload.php has-

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Am i missing something? I have gone through other posts as well
Where people suggested to-

- load database in each function where i use db.
- do not chain the query(which i will try once this is done).
- change the group_name.

And i am using XAMPP server, database is fine(i am seeing the table,data in it).
did all,still i get error!!

Comment: Can you please show the line where you load database.

Comment: thanx for reply @Whirlwind but,where will it be? i haven't loaded in any my model or controller or view? can u suggest how to?

Comment: This error says your database is not loaded.As I see you already loaded database at autoload.In that case check your database config is OK like username dbname dbdriver etc.

Comment: Oh, yes, he's using autoloading. @varunkumar - There are two ways of loading database. Either using autoload or with $this->load->database(); Obviously you are using an autoload method, so do what Shaiful Islam pointed.

Comment: What i have to do @ShaifulIslam can u give me specific? i am trying to understand and learn

Comment: Its hard to produce your problem where everything is OK.Check your db connection is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Keep the case true
$this->load->model("Testquery",'',TRUE);

Answer (score 0):

You must need to load the database .

```
class Testdb extends CI_Controller
   {
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model("testquery");
    }
    public function Index()
    {
       $data['results'] = $this->testquery->query1();
       $this->load->view("view_db");
    }
   }
```

Comment: In Config.php file u can load like this also                                   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: i have done this in my config file itself, and yet i tried in controller as you suggested,the error remains. no change!!

Comment: Try this line in testquery model          function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

Comment: try this $this->load->database('default',TRUE);

Answer (score 0):

Add `__construct()` methods to both controller and model.
You don't need to omit those.

Comment: Yes,done for good understanding. But doesn't solve the problem!!

Comment: Try with `$query = $this->db->get('color');`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in.... same error!! just the method name changes as i changed according to ur code

Comment: Please follow documentation strictly. Load your model with capital as should. Follow instructions from CI/docs/model page and confirm that simple query doesn't work again or affirmate that problem is solved.

Comment: Well, copied the code and created models,controllers as suggested by codeigniter @Tpojka it didn't help, still the same error, thanx anyways

Comment: Is that fresh CI installation? What version of CI is used in application?

Comment: Yes, installed couple of days ago, CI 2.2.1

Comment: Put this in controller to check relation with database:
`echo $this->db->count_all('color');`
Make new method and put this command in it.
also, your method's names should start with lower case.

Comment: :( no, still the fatal error, db connection is fine, other things are also fine, not able to identify the problem.

Comment: Check yor server PHP version with phpinfo() function and MySQL version and compare to CI requirements. Also I suggest to set this issue onto CI forums. Can't tell more. If last tested method doesn't work, you can clearly tell that there is non functional installation/application.

Comment: Sorry for couldn't help. I hope you'll solve it soon. Just post solution here once again.